# AttributeError: module 'tweepy' has no attribute 'Client'

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I am working with the tweepy library and cannot get past authentication. For some reason, I keep getting the error:

AttributeError: module 'tweepy' has no attribute 'Client'

I have the latest version of tweepy installed.

Code:

```
import time
import tweepy


client = tweepy.Client(consumer_key=api_key,
                       consumer_secret=api_secret,
                       access_token=access_token,
                       access_token_secret=access_token_secret)

response = client.create_tweet(text='hello world')

print(response)
```

my tokens are saved as variables and not included in post for obvious reasons ;)

Comment: Is the file you're showing us called `tweepy.py`? Or do you have another file with that name?

Comment: the file is called bot.py

Comment: Are you sure this is version 4 of Tweepy?

Comment: you can do dir(tweepy) to see attributes and methods in your version of tweepy.  tweepy.__version__ will show the version. My version of 3.9.0 does not have the Client attribute

Comment: I am on version 4.5 i believe :/

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, then I installed a later version and my error got resolved.

```
pip install tweepy==4.10.1
```